# -[NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0xd3c21f0> '(null)') deallocated while still in use

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `TableView` to display data i am using `UITableViewCell` nib file for loading cells I am displaying `UILabel` in cell. When scrolling the table view i am getting below error in console

> 2013-07-09 11:44:54.048 Project[19283:a0b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock
>   dealloc]: lock ( '(null)') deallocated
>   while still in use 2013-07-09 11:44:54.049 Project[19283:a0b] ***
>   Break on _NSLockError() to debug. 2013-07-09 11:44:54.140
>   Project[19283:a0b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock
>   ( '(null)') deallocated while still in
>   use 2013-07-09 11:44:54.140 Project[19283:a0b] *** Break on
>   _NSLockError() to debug. 2013-07-09 11:44:54.207 Project[19283:a0b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock ( '(null)') deallocated while still in use 2013-07-09 11:44:54.207
>   Project[19283:a0b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.

How can we remove this error

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/299

Comment: Well, are you using `NSRecursiveLock` anywhere? If not directly, try to find the component that is using this class. Also, add a breakpoint on `_NSLockError` and post the stack trace.

Comment: No I am not using NSRecursiveLock